# ffmpeg error message when merging frames into video

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

I am collecting a list of frames into a video using ffmpeg. I have previously had great success with this, but I now experience an error when I execute the command `ffmpeg -i %d.jpg -c:v huffyuv test.avi`:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2-2~bpo8+2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='2~bpo8+2' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-libtesseract --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --disable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-openal --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-chromaprint --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.100 / 57. 64.100
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, image2, from '%d.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1537x673 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1537:673], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[swscaler @ 0x7f627174a2c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[huffyuv @ 0x7f62717821c0] Width must be even for this colorspace.
[huffyuv @ 0x7f627173b5e0] ff_frame_thread_encoder_init failed
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> huffyuv (native))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

I noticed that the error message contains `Width must be even for this colorspace.` I'm not sure what this actually means though, all the frames have the same dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm not sure what this actually means though*

What it says. `1537` is an odd number. You can crop one column of pixels out.

```
ffmpeg -i %d.jpg -vf crop=1536:673:0:0 -c:v huffyuv test.avi
```

Here the rightmost column of pixels is removed. Change third value in crop to `1` to remove leftmost column. To avoid cropping, you have to save the video as RGB.

```
ffmpeg -i %d.jpg -pix_fmt rgb24 -c:v huffyuv test.avi
```

But this won't help your compression efficiency.